# dot net nuke upgrade prompt for host login blocking password recovery

Tags: passwords, dotnetnuke, recovery

I am moving a copy from server a to server b and server b is asking for the DNN version to be upgraded.  The problem is we do not have the host password.  I tried to upload a password recovery file via FTP and we cannot see it since everything keeps redirecting to this upgrade.  Is there a way to stop the upgrade redirect so we can get the host password and then re-enable it??

```
  Upgrade
 Current Version - 06.02.08
  Upgrade - Version 07.02.01

 You are about to upgrade your website to a more recent version of the application.      Applying upgrades on a consistent basis is the best way to ensure that you are protecting the integrity of your investment and the security of your users and assets. Before proceeding with the automated upgrade process please ensure that:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the upgrade fire off without typing in a password, just go to /install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade and it should run the upgrade without needing to login as HOST. then you can recover the password afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a server which ask for a DNN upgrade. The upgrade process will run only if you've update files with an upgrade package.
Moreover, the 2 versions mentionned are the assembly version and the database version. Moving DNN from a server to another server doesn't modify none of them. Did you copied the database too? I suspect that your dnn copy is connected to another database which is in DNN 6.2.8. It could explain why dnn is attempting to upgrade it.
Regarding the recovery of the host password, I don't know how to proceed. Haven't you a superuser account on this dnn instance?

Comment: we did an install on the new server first.  Then uploaded files and old DB.  Pointed to the old DB after we had a working default install running.  We tried just moving the files and DB to the new server but would just error out??  Config file was updated to point to the new path and still no luck..  The upgrade will not work with any of the superuser accounts...  Am I missing a step in  the moving of this site?  As you can see I am not a DNN guy...

Comment: I suggest you to remove all files in the new website folder and to recopy original files from the server a. You probably only have to change the 2 connection strings which are stored in the web.config. Check the PortalAlias table to check if it contains a valid HttpAlias for your new server in order to avoid a redirect. If you use a sql server login, don't forget to verify if this user exists on your new SQL Server and give it a db_owner access to the restored database.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `web.config` and make sure `AutoUpgrade` is set to `False`.

For the password issue, do you have the password for any other users?
If so, I believe you can go into the `AspNetUsers` table and copy the `PasswordHash/Salt` of that user to the `PasswordHash/Salt` of the admin user.  Then, you should be able to login with the Admin username and the other user's password.

> Note: Please make sure you have a database backup before trying this.